# insert values dynamically in mysql database in java swing application

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, prepared-statement

i want to insert Employee information into mysql database in java swing application in that id field is auto increment then how to call PreparedStatement in question

```
          PreparedStatement pStatement;
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         System.out.println("Connection Established");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
        pStatement=conn.prepareStatement(query,ps.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
       pStatement.execute(query);
        ps.setString(2, fname);
        ps.setString(3, lname);
        ps.setString(4, email);
        ps.setString(5, sex);
        ps.setString(6, year);
        ps.setString(7, branch);

        rs = pStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
    while (rs.next()) {
        sid = String.valueOf(rs.getInt(1));
    }

        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
```

Comment: And your question exactly is...?

Answer (score 2):

Create following class:

```
public class Employee {
    /*
     * VARIABLES
     */
    private String fname    = "";
    private String lname    = "";
    private String email    = "";
    private String sex      = "";
    private String year     = "";
    private String branch   = "";

    /*
     * CONSTRUCOR
     */
    public Employee(String fname, String lname, String email, String sex, String year, String branch) {
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.email = email;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.year = year;
        this.branch = branch;
    }


    /*
     * METHODS
     */
    public String getInsertSQL() {
        return "INSERT INTO employees (fname, lname, email, sex, year, branch) VALUES ("
                + "'" + fname + "', '" + lname + "', '" + email + "', '" + sex + "', '" + year + "', '" + branch + "');";
    }

    /*
     * GETTER AND SETTER
     */
    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getBranch() {
        return branch;
    }

    public void setBranch(String branch) {
        this.branch = branch;
    }

}
```

Then follow this:

```
Employee e = new Employe ("Peter", "Miller", "peter.miller@pm.com", "male", "2015", "IT");    
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement;
stmt.executeUpdate(e.getInsertSQL());
```

And finally you should have an entry in your database.